# Case when to return multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my table, I would use a decode to display the following values in an everyday scenario, however, I need to display all values in 1 column for a specific report as they correspond to the same item.

T1:

```
Id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V5_Text   
1  1  1  1  0  0   Other    
2  0  1  1  0  1   Other     
3  0  0  1  0  1   QWE    
4  0  0  1  1  0   ABC    
5  1  0  0  0  1   Other
```

I used case when but I cannot seem to return more than 1 value.

```
select id,
case when V1=1, then 'A'
     when V2=1, then 'B'
     when V3=1, then 'C'
     when V4=1, then 'D'
     when V5=1, then v5_text
```

Expected output:

```
1  A,B,C,Other   
2  B,C,Other    
3  C,QWE    
4  C,D,ABC   
5  A,Other
```

Actual Output:

```
1  Other    
2  Other    
3  QWE     
4  ABC    
5  Other
```

Comment: you must either concatenate your strings, or make a JSON in order to return "multiple" values, because OR is lazy: as soon as a criteria is satisfied, it is not evaluated further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the values:

```
select id,
       trim(',' from
            (case when V1 = 1 then 'A,' end) ||
             case when V2 = 1 then 'B,' end) ||
             case when V3 = 1 then 'C,' end) ||
             case when V4 = 1 then 'D,' end) ||
             case when V5 = 1 then v5_text
            )
           )
```

Comment: if I am concatenating, do I even need a case when? Can I achieve this using decode?

Comment: @Skn . . . `case` is much preferable to `decode()` because it is ANSI standard functionality.

Comment: `decode` is essentially an alternative syntax for `case`. Use whichever you prefer, although `case` is generally more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else you have in mind, nor how large this table is, but another way is to "unpivot" that v1...v5 structure and then use listagg()

btw: the first row

```
Id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V5_Text   
1  1  1  1  0  0   Other   
   A  B  C                   -- there is no "other" here
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebef3/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (ID int, V1 int, V2 int, V3 int, V4 int, V5 int, V5_TEXT varchar2(5))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V5_TEXT)
         VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 'Other')
    INTO Table1 (ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V5_TEXT)
         VALUES (2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 'Other')
    INTO Table1 (ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V5_TEXT)
         VALUES (3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'QWE')
    INTO Table1 (ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V5_TEXT)
         VALUES (4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'ABC')
    INTO Table1 (ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V5_TEXT)
         VALUES (5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 'Other')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      id, listagg(alpha,',') within group (order by alpha) codes_concat
from (
    select id, v1, V5_TEXT, 'A' alpha from table1 where v1 = 1 union all
    select id, v2, V5_TEXT, 'B' alpha from table1 where v2 = 1 union all
    select id, v3, V5_TEXT, 'C' alpha from table1 where v3 = 1 union all
    select id, v4, V5_TEXT, 'D' alpha from table1 where v4 = 1 union all
    select id, v5, V5_TEXT, 'Other'   from table1 where v5 = 1 
    ) d
group by
      id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebef3/1/0)**:

```
| ID | CODES_CONCAT |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |        A,B,C |
|  2 |    B,C,Other |
|  3 |      C,Other |
|  4 |          C,D |
|  5 |      A,Other |
```

---

**edit**

if union all offends, then there are other ways:

```
select
      id, listagg(alpha,',') within group (order by alpha) codes_concat
from (
      select 
            id
          , V5_TEXT
          , case when cj.n = 1 then v1
                 when cj.n = 2 then v2
                 when cj.n = 3 then v3
                 when cj.n = 4 then v4
                 when cj.n = 5 then v5 end v1
          , case when cj.n = 1 then 'A'
                 when cj.n = 2 then 'B'
                 when cj.n = 3 then 'C'
                 when cj.n = 4 then 'D'
                 when cj.n = 5 then V5_TEXT end alpha
      from table1
      cross join (
          Select level n from dual connect by level<=5
          ) cj
    ) d
where v1 <> 0
group by
      id

;
```

or unpivot may be used etc. etc.

```
select
      id, listagg(alpha,',') within group (order by alpha) codes_concat
from (
      select
            id, v5_text, v1
          , case when vname = 'V1' then 'A'
                 when vname = 'V2' then 'B'
                 when vname = 'V3' then 'C'
                 when vname = 'V4' then 'D'
                 when vname = 'V5' then v5_text end alpha
      from table1
      UNPIVOT ( 
              v1 FOR( vname ) IN ( v1, v2, v3, v4, v5
              )
          )
    ) d
where v1 <> 0
group by
      id
;
```

Comment: Good idea... but please don't unpivot by way of UNION ALL and multiple passes over the same data. Either use the UNPIVOT operator (which requires Oracle 11.1 or higher), or unpivot by way of a cross product, as unpivoting was done before 11.1.

Comment: @mathguy happy for you to add the requested re-write

Comment: I almost did - then I realized Gordon's solution is more efficient anyway. Unpivoting loses information: after unpivoting, we need to group again by id, an expensive operation. The rows are already grouped by id in the base table, we might as well take advantage of that. Same with ordering: the "tokens" are already ordered (by column order); if we unpivot, we must then order (by `n` in your notation) in `listagg()`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this help you, i test this code with your raw data

```
select id,
rtrim((case v1 when 1 then 'A,' else '' end ||
case v2   when 1 then 'B,' else '' end ||
case v3   when 1 then 'C,' else '' end ||
case  v4  when 1 then 'D,' else '' end ||
case  v5 when 1 then v5_text || ',' else '' end),',')
from table1
```

[image: image of result]